# Upload all wordpress file together using filezilla, without skipping any one of the file

Tags: wordpress, ftp, web-hosting, file-transfer, filezilla

I am trying to upload my wordpress website to my 000webhost.com hosted website using filezilla.

**Problem** : After uploading the wordpress folder completely, filezilla is skipping many of the crucial files is also not storing the failed files under "FAILED TRANSFER"

Is there any setting in filezilla such that it does not skip any file and tranfers all the files within folder's recursively?

Comment: I get errors when there are "failed transfers" as a standard in Filezilla...

Comment: try using a different FTP software ( like fireftp )and -- it is not really a wordpress question .

Comment: I have tried using smartFTP also. But there is no solution

Answer (score 0):

FileZilla's default may be set to skip the file if a file of the same name already exists on the server (upload folder).

You can change this behaviour under the Transfer menu options, select the *Default File Exists Action*, and a dialog pops up, there are a number of choices of what to do by default, I would suggest amending the Uploads section to be *Overwrite file if source file newer*.